# Weird bug on comment deletion. First deletion goes through fine, second one deletes wrong comment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is so weird I had to record a gif to go along with my explanation so that I could present it clearer.

https://imgur.com/a/5eaVgWu

Now here's my explanation on the steps I take in this gif.

- I create 3 comments called "First", "Second" and "Third".
- I refresh the phpMyAdmin so you can see that they're in fact created.
- I inspect their hidden input values so we can confirm that they hold
  the correct and respective IDs.
- Then I delete the "Third" comment and refresh the database so you
  could see that the correct comment has been removed.
- This is where the problem begins. I click to delete "First" comment
  and on my page it looks like I have actually deleted the "First"
  comment, however, in the database we can see that in reality,
  "Second" comment has been deleted and that first is still left there.
- Finally, when I try to delete "Second" comment on the page, I get a
  server error in the console. The error is that I'm trying to delete a
  non-existent record.
- Meanwhile, comment "First" still exist in the database.

My form for deletion:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ $comment->id }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('delete') }}
    <button class='submit-btn delete-comment' type='submit' name='commentDelete'>X</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript Ajax:

```
$('.delete-comment').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var button = $(this);
    var flexbox = button.parents().eq(2);
    var commentId = $("input[name=comment_id]").val();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlDeleteComment,
        data: {
            commentId: commentId,
            _method: 'delete',
            _token: token
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        flexbox.remove();
    })
});
```

Comment deletion function:

```
public function deleteComment(Request $request){
    $commentId = $request['commentId'];
    $comment = Comment::find($commentId);
    $comment->delete();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated since I thought about the issue for quite some time and I haven't figured where my problem is.

Comment: Isn’t your commentId query just going to give all inputs with name comment_id, not the one associated with the button? I assume you meant to run the query on `flexbox`

Comment: Wow, now that you've pointed that out, I realize how obvious my mistake is. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that instead of rendering each delete button as a single form, my suggestion would be to have a single AJAX function that accepts a value, which is triggered by buttons (not form submissions) with a data value. For example

```
<button class="btn-delete" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}">Delete</button>
```

You don't need a form or a hidden field or a CSRF token. The AJAX handles the rest.

```
$('.btn-delete').on('click', function() {

    var id = $(this).data('id'); // Gets the value from the data-id field

    $.ajax({
        url: urlDeleteComment,   // I'm assuming you already have this set somewhere
        method: 'POST',
        data: 'comment_id='+id,
        success: function(response) {
            // ...
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            // ...
        }
    });

});
```

This will send a request to the server with the commend ID of the button that was pressed.

I would also recommend using success/error functions so that you can handle a scenario where the deletion fails. (Such as the comment has already been deleted or you do not have permissions to delete this comment).

As for the server side code itself, you can just handle things as you are. I'd recommend returning a 200 if things went well or a 4xx/5xx error so that you can trigger your AJAX error function should anything go wrong.

As for the actual on screen deletion. I'd recommend wrapping the comment in a `div` with an ID of some sort that matches the ID on the delete button. For example:

```
<div class="comment" data-comment="{{ $comment->id}}">
    <!-- Your comment here -->
    <button class="btn-delete" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}">Delete</button>
</div>
```

So that when you want to remove the comment from the screen, inside your AJAX success callback:

```
// ...
success: function(response) {
    $('.comment[data-comment="' + id + '"]').slideUp();
}
// ...
```

---

The reason why I'm suggesting an alternative rather than attempting to fix the current method of approach (which is possible) is that there is a lot of extra work/junk that is involved with rendering a form each time you display a button.

Using generic AJAX calls that accept a parameter from a button press is typically a preferred method of building these style of applications as it cuts down a lot of work required to not only build this in the first place, but also maintain it in the long term.

Comment: Thanks, even though I found the mistake of my code thanks to Sami Kuhmonen, I believe I prefer your way over mine.